# Create a Dashboard Template Component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I know have to render components within other components. What I want to do here is create a dashboard component that I can use to wrap around the content of the component I am calling. Here is my dashboard component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <navbar></navbar>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <sidebar></sidebar>

                <!-- Main -->
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>

        <foot></foot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Dashboard mounted.')
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is the main component...

```
<template>
    <Dashbaord>

        <main role="main" class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 ml-auto px-4">
            Main Content
        </main>

    </Dashbaord>
</template>

<script>
    import Dashbaord from "./../../components/dashboard";
    import LogIndexItem from "./LogIndexItem";

    export default {
        components: {
            Dashbaord,
            LogIndexItem
        },
    }
</script>
```

In my head this should work but only the dashboard renders and not the main content.

Comment: In the main-component, you seem to pass `main` as a slot, but in the Dashboard-component you're using `router-view` and not a slot. You should either use a slot, or set up the router correctly, but not mixing the two options.

Comment: `main` was just the html tag and not a component name. But "slots" let me explore that. I'm new to this so loads to learn.

Comment: well, `main` is used inside `Dashbaord` in the main component. If you nest components, you typically need slots for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @cello for pointing me in the right direction. I managed to get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add slot tag  to use slot in dashboard component...

Dashboard Component

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <navbar></navbar>
    
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <sidebar></sidebar>
    
                    <!-- Main -->
                    <slot name="main"></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <foot></foot>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Dashboard mounted.')
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Main Component...

```
<template>
    <Dashbaord>
        <template v-slot:main>
            <main role="main" class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 ml-auto px-4">
                Main Content
            </main>
        </template>
    </Dashbaord>
</template>
```

see here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html